# Estimate Shipping Default value

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping

I added the city field for the "Estimate Shipping and Tax" part with the function isCityActive in this file vendor\magento\module-checkout\Block\Cart\LayoutProcessor.php

The city field appear on the checkout page but there isn't default value.
For the others fields, by default there is the value of the default shipping address.

I think that I have to modify the LayoutProcessor.php file to add by default the city from the customer default shipping address but I don't how to do this.

LayoutProcessor.php :

```
namespace Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart;


class LayoutProcessor implements \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessorInterface { 
/**
 * @var \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\AttributeMerger
 */
protected $merger;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\Collection
 */
protected $countryCollection;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\Collection
 */
protected $regionCollection;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface
 */
protected $defaultShippingAddress = null;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Directory\Model\TopDestinationCountries
 */
private $topDestinationCountries;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\AttributeMerger $merger
 * @param \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\Collection $countryCollection
 * @param \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\Collection $regionCollection
 * @param \Magento\Directory\Model\TopDestinationCountries $topDestinationCountries
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\AttributeMerger $merger,
    \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\Collection $countryCollection,
    \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\Collection $regionCollection,
    \Magento\Directory\Model\TopDestinationCountries $topDestinationCountries = null
) {
    $this->merger = $merger;
    $this->countryCollection = $countryCollection;
    $this->regionCollection = $regionCollection;
    $this->topDestinationCountries = $topDestinationCountries ?:
        \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(\Magento\Directory\Model\TopDestinationCountries::class);
}

/**
 * Show City in Shipping Estimation
 *
 * @return bool
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
protected function isCityActive()
{
    // return false;
    return true;
}

/**
 * Show State in Shipping Estimation
 *
 * @return bool
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
protected function isStateActive()
{
    return false;
}

/**
 * Process js Layout of block
 *
 * @param array $jsLayout
 * @return array
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
 */
public function process($jsLayout)
{
    $elements = [
        'city' => [
            'visible' => $this->isCityActive(),
            'formElement' => 'input',
            'label' => __('City'),
            'value' =>  null
        ],
        'country_id' => [
            'visible' => true,
            'formElement' => 'select',
            'label' => __('Country'),
            'options' => [],
            'value' => null
        ],
        'region_id' => [
            'visible' => true,
            'formElement' => 'select',
            'label' => __('State/Province'),
            'options' => [],
            'value' => null
        ],
        'postcode' => [
            'visible' => true,
            'formElement' => 'input',
            'label' => __('Zip/Postal Code'),
            'value' => null
        ]
    ];

    if (!isset($jsLayout['components']['checkoutProvider']['dictionaries'])) {
        $jsLayout['components']['checkoutProvider']['dictionaries'] = [
            'country_id' => $this->countryCollection->loadByStore()->setForegroundCountries(
                $this->topDestinationCountries->getTopDestinations()
            )->toOptionArray(),
            'region_id' => $this->regionCollection->addAllowedCountriesFilter()->toOptionArray(),
        ];
    }
    if (isset($jsLayout['components']['block-summary']['children']['block-shipping']['children']
        ['address-fieldsets']['children'])
    ) {
        $fieldSetPointer = &$jsLayout['components']['block-summary']['children']['block-shipping']
        ['children']['address-fieldsets']['children'];
        $fieldSetPointer = $this->merger->merge($elements, 'checkoutProvider', 'shippingAddress', $fieldSetPointer);
        $fieldSetPointer['region_id']['config']['skipValidation'] = true;
    }
    return $jsLayout;
}
```

}

[image]

Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to create your own module to override the `LayoutProcessor.php`, instead of editing Magento core script. Because that's a bad idea.

Then you may need to set the value of this line in the city block:

```
$elements = [
        'city' => [
            'visible' => $this->isCityActive(),
            'formElement' => 'input',
            'label' => __('City'),
            'value' =>  null
        ],
```

change `null` to your desired value.